# USB device is not detected properly

Tags: usb, usb-otg

I am using am335x board.USB device is detected when it is inserted while booting up the board. after the board is booted up, i unplug the device and is inserted again,it is not detected.usb driver switches off the vbus session when a device is disconnected from its port.every time i need to start the session using the command "echo F > /proc/driver/musb_hdrc".How to make it auto detect? If anyone has faced this problem,please post reply.

Answer (score 0):

If faced the same problem. It seems that when you use ULPI mode, starting vbus does not work.
Have a look on a newer kernel in file drivers/usb/musb/omap2430.c
When an USB_EVENT_ID got notified, you should turn on vbus independtly of the mode your otg is working.

hope that helps.